# How to make an incoming call in genymotion emulator in android?

Tags: android-emulator, emulators, genymotion

How can I make an incoming call in genymotion emulator in android?

I am using genymotion emulator to run and test my app.

In the native emulator DDMS, we can make a fake call. Can this be done using the genymotion emulator?

Comment: @Stephen  my English is poor so ... thanks for edit :) do you have idea about my question ??

Comment: You can't simulate a call in Genymotion 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198871/how-to-make-incoming-call-in-genymotion-emulator-in-android

Comment: I don't think this question will benefit Android *end-users*... I can't think any cases where general user want to do this. Anyway, you have posted this question [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198871/how-to-make-incoming-call-in-genymotion-emulator-in-android). Cross-post is discouraged, moreover if it's off-topic on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i found call function in geymotion :) #thanks @Rajkiran

The Phone widget allows to test applications relying on telephony features and observe their behavior when receiving a call or a text message.

[image]

To use the Phone widget, click  or Ctrl + 8.
**To simulate an incoming call:**
1.Enter an incoming phone number.
2.Click Call.

**To simulate an incoming message:**

1.Enter an incoming phone number.
 2.Enter a text message.
 3.Click Send message.

The text message is displayed in the virtual device via a notification and can also be read in the Messaging application.

:( This feature is only available with Indie and Business licenses.